# Server and Client not working the way they should when dealing with a message longer than 1 character

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, server

It is a simple hangman game written in python and using sockets.

Ok this is my client program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import time
import sys

por=(sys.argv[2])
Zaphod_Beeblerox = int(por)


print ("To exit from the game at any time please type and send QUIT")


def Main():
    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = Zaphod_Beeblerox
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = input("Would you like a GAME or QUIT?")

    while message != 'QUIT':
        s.send("NEW_GAME".encode('utf-8'))
        dat = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(dat)
        msg = "a"
        data = 'nowt'
        while msg != 'QUIT':
            while "score" not in (data):
                if (msg) in (lowercase):
                    msg = input("->")
                    s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
                    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                    if "_" not in (data):
                        print (data)
                        s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
                        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                        print (data)
                        break
                    else:
                        print (data)
                else:
                    break
            break
        break

    print("Exiting")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

This is my server program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import socket
import random
import time

por=(sys.argv[1])
Zaphod_Beeblerox = int(por)



def Main():
#setting up the connection
    host = ''
    port = Zaphod_Beeblerox
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
# setting the beginning parameters  
    secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
    guesses=0
    letters_guessed = []
    word = []
    for x in range(len(secret_word)):
        word.append('_ ')
#listening for a connection and then announcing it.
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(addr))

#while testing i used this but it is cheating
#   print (secret_word)

    while True:
        guess = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print (guess)
        if guess == 'NEW_GAME':
            c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word)).encode('utf-8'))
#if the guess is a single lowercase letter
        elif len(guess) == 1:
                    if (guess) in (letters_guessed): #if already guessed
                            ins = random.choice(insult)
                            c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word) + "\n" + "\n" + ins).encode('utf-8'))
                    elif (guess) in (lowercase):
#if it is the final letter
                                if (guess).join(word) == secret_word:
                                    score = guesses/2
                                    scr = 10.5 - scor
                                    scrr = str(scr)
                                    print("Score =", + scr)
                                    Quote = random.choice(Hitch_Quote)
                                    c.send((("\n Your score is: ") + (scrr) + "\n" + "\n" (Quote) + "\n" + "\n" (secret_word)).encode('utf-8'))
                                    break
#                                else:
#                                    c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word)).encode('utf-8'))

                                elif (guess) in (secret_word):
                                    for index, letter in enumerate(secret_word):
                                        if letter == guess:
                                            word[index] = guess
                                            letters_guessed.append(guess)
                                    Quote = random.choice(Hitch_Quote)
                                    c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word) + "\n" + "\n" + Quote).encode('utf-8'))

                                else:
                                    letters_guessed.append(guess)
                                    guesses = guesses + 1
                                    ins = random.choice(insult)
                                    c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word) + "\n" + "\n" + ins).encode('utf-8'))
                                if ''.join(word) == secret_word:
                                    score = guesses/2
                                    scr = 10.5 - score
                                    scrr = str(scr)
                                    print("Score =", + scr)
                                    Quote = random.choice(Hitch_Quote)
                                    c.send((("\n \n \nYour score is: ") + (scrr) + "\n" + "\n" + (Quote) + "\n" + "\n").encode('utf-8'))
                                    break
                    else:# if isnt in lowercase
                        break
        elif len(guess) == len(secret_word): #word guesses
            while guess != secret_word:
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
                guesses = guesses + 1
                ins = random.choice(insult)
                c.send(("\n %s"%''.join(word) + "\n" + "\n" + ins).encode('utf-8'))
            split = list(guess)
            if set(split).issubset(lowercase) == True:
                if guess == secret_word:
                    print(secret_word)
                    score = guesses/2
                    scr = 10.5 - score
                    scrr = str(scr)
                    print("Score =", + scr)
                    Quote = random.choice(Hitch_Quote)
                    c.send((secret_word).encode('utf-8'))
                    c.send((("\n \n \nYour score is: ") + (scrr) + "\n" + "\n" + (Quote) + "\n" + "\n").encode('utf-8'))
                    time.sleep(3)
                    break
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
        if not guess:
            break

    print("GAME OVER")
    c.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The issue is that when i send a word guess of the right length but wrong it quits, it should send an insult and the _ and wait for another message but it doesn't. 
I have deleted some lists from this code or it gets too long. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: From a glance at your code: you're assuming one `send()` corresponds to one `reveice()`. With sockets, it doesn't. You need an application protocol to provide message framing.

Comment: That sounds complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I umm just did something that probably isn't going to get me 100% of the marks for this assignment however it works lol!

I just changed the bytes it would accept as a single message and send as a single message> :)